# Unable to generate svg to pdf from PHP imagick

Tags: php, server, imagick

We have migrated our app from one server to other server. In first server svg to pdf using PHP imagick is working good but in second server imagick returns empty content after conversion. Please help me to resolve the issue. or please provide me what could be reason for this issue.

The code used for the conversion is given below:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svgContent);
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');
echo 'Test1: '. $im->getImageBlob();
$PDFContent = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' . base64_encode($im);
echo 'Test2: '. $PDFContent;
```

Both Test1 and Test2 displays empty.

when I try $im->setImageFormat('png'); its working.

Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870973/output-a-pdf-file-using-imagic-and-php? I've not seen `image/pdf` before.

Comment: @user3783243 yes tried that too same issue $im->getImageBlob() is empty.

Comment: If you wanna go bold. You could use MPDF or something similar, since it allows to generate PDFs using images (As in place the image inside)